# Add value in ListView at 1st Row and 3rd column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, row

I want to add the values in multiple row and column, but the condition is that I wish to add value at a particular row and column.

```
// this is my method get called with struct type List 
void showbind(List<binddata> bindinfo)  
{
    foreach (var item in bindinfo)
    {
        string ip = item.serIp;    // structure items
        int col = item.column;
        string sc = item.scipt;
        string o_ut=item.output;

        // here I'm getting the index of row...
        int i = Array.IndexOf(Program.CheckIp.Keys.ToArray(), "ip");  

        // here I want to add the output value at the "col" 
        // number column..... "lstVwServerList" is the item id.
        lstVwServerList.Columns[col].Text = o_ut;
    }
}
```

Comment: lstVwServerList[i].Columns[col].Text = o_ut;

Comment: no.. it is showing error.

Comment: What error? Is the number of rows in lstVwServerList the same number of rows in bindinfo?

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'

Comment: See Codeman answer : lstVwServerList.Items[i].SubItems[col].Text = o_ut;

Comment: Yess  thanks for your answer

Comment: no... Bindinfo is the structure having fix 4 rows but in lstVwServerList having dynamic rows and column it depends upon the user how much he/she wants add.

Comment: Normally I bind to a DataTable because it contains the columns names and column types.  When you do a query of the DataTable you will get a List<DataRow> which you gives the flexibility to do a lot of things.  You can create a new table simply by using the method CopyToDataTable(). When you change the results of the query (List<DataRow>) the original table values change because the list is a link to the original table and not new rows.Then your showbind method would be List<DataRow> bindinfo and make the code simpler.  With the current code you have to lookup the bind results to the listview.

Comment: Ok here some more information related to my problem..... Im adding the columns and respective subitems for each rows as following  for (int i = 0; i < lstVwServerList.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    lstVwServerList.Items[i].SubItems.Add("");
                }                                     which is reside in other public function, and also lstVwServerlist is pubic... but when im doing lstVwServerList.Items[i].SubItems[col].Text = o_ut; here subitem count is only showing 1 which is 1st column itself.......so please....

Comment: Ok Thanks....Finally I have solved my problem... thankyou you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example I have listView1 with 3 columns, add 2 rows and change 2 value in each row; please customize it for yourself.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] row = { "qqq", "ddd", "ccc" };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    listView1.Items[0].Text = "hi";

    row = new string[3];
    row[0] = "vvv";
    row[1] = "ooo";
    row[2] = "zzz";
    listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    listView1.Items[1].SubItems[1].Text = "hi";
}
```

Comment: Sorry,, But it is showing another error for subitem[col]...saying InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.,,even listview has three columns

Comment: The line what im using to add columns in listview is lstVwServerList.Columns.Add(txtBxColName.Text, 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);    But at time to adding values it is showing only 1 column has the listview. at index 0.

Comment: More info: In my example , listview.View = Detail.

Comment: Yes I used that, still it is not working..Showing same error

Comment: Sir another question is that....I m running a thread in code. Thread is taking all the element from the check list view , but after completion of  thread execution the checked item are getting uncheck automatically. can you provide me any solution to prevent that.

Comment: Ok Thanks....Finally I have solved my problem... thankyou you guys for your help.